# How to preserve a GUID/Unique Id when passed as Dynamic param to a Kusto function

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

I have a Kusto function, let's call it `B,` which accepts dynamic content and then uses `mv-expand` to perform some queries and returns the data to the called function, let's call it `A.` The returned data table should be joined back to the original data to perform the rest of the operations in `A.`

To perform the join operation on a unique ID, I am extending the original table in function A with GUIDs and then converting it to a scalar to pass it to B, as shown below.

```
let x= datatable(EndTime:datetime, Event:string) [
    datetime(1910-06-11), "foo",
    datetime(1930-01-01), "bar",
    datetime(1930-01-01), "foo bar"
];
let data = x
| project EndTime, Event
| extend Id = new_guid();
data;
let scalar_events =  toscalar
(
data
| project scalar  = pack_all()
| summarize scalar = make_list(scalar)
);
print(scalar_events)
```

The GUIDs in the data table and the ones in the scalar_events are different after the toscalar operation; I also tried converting the IDs to string and then passing; even the stringified GUIDs are regenerated, and it does not retain the original values.

```
let x= datatable(EndTime:datetime, Event:string) [
    datetime(1910-06-11), "foo",
    datetime(1930-01-01), "bar",
    datetime(1930-01-01), "foo bar"
];
let data = x
| project EndTime, Event
| extend Id = tostring(new_guid());
data;
let scalar_events =  toscalar
(
data
| project scalar  = pack_all()
| summarize scalar = make_list(scalar)
);
print(scalar_events);
```

Is there a way to preserve this and return it to be used for joining? Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: while your use case isn't too clear (to me, at least), you could try using the [`materialize` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction) when you calculate `data`

Comment: Hi @YoniL., Thank you. Please let me know If you want any clarification on the use case. I will check the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @YoniL pointed out, this is because of how Kusto preprocesses its queries; it does not work how we expect a traditional programming language to work. To get around this problem and tell Kusto to use the actual data without re-evaluating it, we need the [Materialize function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction):

```
let x= datatable(EndTime:datetime, Event:string) [
    datetime(1910-06-11), "foo",
    datetime(1930-01-01), "bar",
    datetime(1930-01-01), "foo bar"
];
let data = materialize
(
  x | extend Id = tostring(new_guid())
);
data;
let scalar_events =  toscalar
(
data
| project scalar  = pack_all()
| summarize scalar = make_list(scalar)
);
print(scalar_events);
```